# Where to store node.js project own libraries?

Tags: node.js

In a NodeJS project, the folder `./node_modules` keeps all project modules and dependencies.

My project have some libraries like `dbConnect.js`, `utils.js`, `messages.js`, `constants.js`, etc... They are not public libraries that can be found in an online repository. I wrote them specifically for the project. So I store them in **./lib**:

```
My project/
  /node_modules
    express
    cheriio
    <lot of modules folders installed with npm>

  /lib
    dbConnect.js
    utils.js
    messages.js
    constants.js
    common.js
    <other project .js files>
```

These libraries may use some modules in `./node_modules`.
To load the modules I use:

```
const CHEERIO = require('cheerio');
const UTILS = require('../lib/common.js');
const COMMON = require('./lib/utils.js');
```

The problem is `UTILS` and `COMMON` may not be found **depending on which order they were required**:

> Error: Cannot find module '../lib/common.js'

I've tried `../lib/common.js`, `./lib/common.js` `./common.js`

My queston is, how do I properly store the project own libraries so they can be properly loaded? Should they be stored in the project root folder?

Comment: The path depends from where the file  that requires these libraries is, if the file is at the same level of lib folder you may do lib/common.js .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the files as feel logical. Like you might wants to put all you api controlars in one folder, Your db connections and queries in one folder, services in one folder. Its completely depends on you. You just have to use the relative path from where you are requiring the file to where the file is located. For example if you are requiring a file from same folder the './file_name' should be ok. But if you want to include a file one directory up then you have to use '../filename' as path inside require.